# SWRevealViewController nib cell not performing segue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

Simply put, I have a slide navigation view controller in my app with a back table VC and a front table VC. A selected cell in the back table VC is supposed to segue to the front table VC (embedded in a navigation VC). To illustrate, here are the isolated pre-change settings and code with it working properly:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is the simplified working code in my back table VC's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let navigationCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NavigationCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    return navigationCell
}
```

Ok, onto the fun part. All I want is to replace the default UITableViewCell shown above with one of my custom cells in a Xib file.  Now I'll illustrate what I modified. First, here's my Xib cell in my `NavigationCell.xib` file. Nothing special.

[image]
[image]

My `NavigationCell` class code is simply

```
import UIKit

class NavigationCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
}
```

Finally, I modified my code in my back table VC to register the Xib and dequeue the custom cell:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let navigationCellNib = UINib(nibName: "NavigationCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.registerNib(navigationCellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "NavigationCell")
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let navigationCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NavigationCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NavigationCell
    return navigationCell
}
```

All other code and specifications remain the same. The storyboard segue for the new custom cell is still from the class `SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController` as shown in the first screenshot for this question. I simply swapped out the default UITableViewCell with my custom Xib cell.

This modification was enough to stop the segue from occurring. With this modification, after I build and run when I slide out the back table VC navigation menu and select one of my custom navigation cells (which display properly), it doesn't trigger any segue. Any thoughts?

Comment: I've used SWRevealController before and this stuff gets tricky. Have you tried making the segue a setController instead of pushController?

Comment: I have switched it back and forth to no avail. When I tap the navigation cell it highlights in the default light grey and triggers the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method but that's as far as it goes.

Comment: Here's a tutorial I used when I was first messing around with SWRevealController http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/ You have most of it setup go to the section titled implementing menu Item selection. it appears You need a segue identifier and prepare for segue method. Also make sure you have the proper sw_front, sw_rear segue identifiers. This is a good tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the help @MatthewLawrenceBailey, unfortunately I have all of those things implemented. The sw_front, sw_rear, and prepareForSegue. I left those code samples out of this question because everything was working before and I only am showing what was changed to make it not work. My navigation cell is not even triggering the prepareForSegue method.

Comment: From the top right pictures it shows you have no segue identifier set for the segue not being called. This could cause the prepare for segue not to trigger. Set it to anything eg. 'segueIdentifier' and then implement  `if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueIdentifier"])` in the prepareForSegue in SWRevealViewController.m its just a little further down in the tutorial from the setting the other segues

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work :-/. I have the sw_front and sw_rear identifiers for the other segues but this segue identifier was blank before when it was working properly. Also the methods shown in that tutorial for the `prepareForSegue` have been deprecated in the framework

Comment: do you have a sw_right identifier? I think It goes from the swRevealController to the view your pushing to.

Comment: I didn't have one when it was working. Here's what I have for segues http://imgur.com/a/AnV4a

Comment: Have you tried taking out the registerNib lines in viewDidLoad? I'm pretty sure you do not have to register nib since you use the cellReuseIdentifier of and its on storyboard.

Comment: That seems to get me one step closer! If I comment everything out in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it works and I have empty navigations cells that segue properly. However, when I try to set the custom Xib outlets in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` then it crashes saying it "unexpectedly found nil". Here's another image for context http://imgur.com/a/C3IUm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm an idiot. I had to perform the segue programmatically in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MySegue", sender: self)
}
```